# Stirling number of the second kind problem

Tags: combinatorics

> Given that $S(r,n)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind, how do I show that
>   $$S(r,3)=\frac{1}{2}(3^{r-1}+1)-2^{r-1}$$
>   I couldn't get the additional $1$ in the parentheses.

Consider distributing $r$ distinct objects into $3$ identical boxes such that no box is empty,

**(1)** Each of the $r$ objects can go into any of the $3$ boxes,
$$\frac{3^r}{3!}=\frac{1}{2}(3^{r-1})\quad \Leftarrow \text{ I don't get a whole number here.}$$
**(2)** Minus the case where all $r$ objects go into the same box,
$$1$$
**(3)** Minus the case where there is $1$ empty box, in other words $S(r,2)$,
$$2^{r-1}-1$$
So what have I missed out? (My mistake should be in **(1)**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think you're getting $\frac{3^r}{3!}$ because you're saying "put the objects in three different boxes in all possible ways.  If I forget the order of the boxes, that means I've created each possible assignment $3!$ times". But that's not quite right.  All the possible arrangements show up $3!$ times except the one where you put all the objects in one box.  That only shows up $3$ times.  So the you have 
$N\cdot 3! + 3 = 3^r$ where $N$ is the number of arrangements besides the one with all the objects in one box.  So $N = \frac{3^r - 3}{3!}$, so the total number of arrgangements is $N+1 = \frac{1}{2} (3^{r-1} - 1) + 1$ which is $\frac{1}{2}(3^{r-1}+1)$